# Handling Encoded Responses in Salesforce OAuth2 External Credentials

Tags: integration, callout, oauth2, authentication, externalcredentials

I'm dealing with a specific issue in Salesforce related to External Credentials with OAuth2 protocol. The main problem is that Salesforce doesn't properly accept encoded responses from our authentication server. As a workaround, I attempted to add a `Accept-Encoding: identity` header in the OAuth2 configuration, but it's not being included in the outgoing requests. This seems to be specific to OAuth2, as other protocols don't have this issue.

Details:

- Configured a External Credential with OAuth2.
- Salesforce and Apex seem unable to process encoded responses from our auth server.
  Tried adding `Accept-Encoding: identity` as a custom header, but it's not effective in OAuth2 setup.
- I've raised a support ticket with Salesforce, but they were unable to assist due to our current plan not covering developer support.

This is the credential setup:
[image: credentials]

When I do the callout using apex with the header it work just fine. Without it I receive just some gibberish.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

request.setEndpoint('https://adsasd.dev/oauth/v2/token');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'identity');

String body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=adsasd&client_secret=asdasd&scope=salesforce';
request.setBody(body);

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

I'm hoping someone in the community might have encountered and resolved a similar issue or could offer some guidance.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007W8aydSAB

Comment: based on the thread above, one possible solution architecture is API Gateway / Proxy - add/remove headers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately as of now sf does not support custom headers for Oauth2 protocol. To work around this limitation you have to create a custom auth provider, where you can do the auth call with the header.